# Creating a tab activity with one activity and views. Getting "could not create tab content because could not find view with id"

Tags: android

I followed the example in the Android website to create a tab activity with multiple activities. Now I am trying to have it as Single activity and multiple views. I am getting the following exception

Java.lang.RuntimeException : Could not create tab content because could not find the view by id

This is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootTbl" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />          
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/assignedLin" >
                <TextView android:id="@+id/dateassigned" style="@style/deftxtView"/>
                <ListView android:id="@+id/assignedListView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="300dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>     

                <!--TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/assignedTbl" >
                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/dateassigned" style="@style/deftxtView"/>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <ListView android:id="@+id/assignedListView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="300dp"/>
                </TableRow>
                </TableLayout-->

                <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/acceptedTbl" >
                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/dateaccepted" style="@style/deftxtView"/>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <ListView android:id="@+id/acceptedListView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="300dp"/>
                </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my java file

```
package com.tcs.mServices;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.tcs.mLib.DBAdapter;
import com.tcs.mServicesBO.FFA_CONTACT_DETAILS;
import com.tcs.mServicesBO.FFA_SERVICE_REQUEST;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;

public class TabActivityScreen extends TabActivity {

    private static DBAdapter dbAdapter;
    private static Context context;
    private static InteractiveAdapter interactiveAdapter;
    private static ListView assignedListView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabactivityscreen);

        ArrayList<FFA_SERVICE_REQUEST> ffa_Service_Requests=(ArrayList<FFA_SERVICE_REQUEST>) this.getIntent().getExtras().get("ffa_service_RequestBO");
        ArrayList<FFA_CONTACT_DETAILS> ffa_Contact_Details=(ArrayList<FFA_CONTACT_DETAILS>) this.getIntent().getExtras().get("ffa_Contact_DetailsBO");

    /* 
     * Tab Related Code
     * 
     */ 


    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost       
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    final Intent assignedIntent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
    final Intent acceptedIntent;
    final Intent returnedIntent;
    final Intent completedIntent;



    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    assignedIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, AssignedActivity.class);
    assignedIntent.putExtra("ffa_service_RequestBO", ffa_Service_Requests);
    assignedIntent.putExtra("ffa_Contact_DetailsBO", ffa_Contact_Details);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
   /* spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ASSIGNED").setIndicator("Assigned")
                  .setContent(assignedIntent);*/
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ASSIGNED").setIndicator("Assigned")
    .setContent(R.id.assignedLin);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);   


    acceptedIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, AcceptedActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
/*    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ACCEPTED").setIndicator("Accepted")
                  .setContent(acceptedIntent);*/
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ACCEPTED").setIndicator("Accepted")
    .setContent(R.id.acceptedTbl);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    returnedIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, ReturnedActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("RETURNED").setIndicator("Returned")
                        .setContent(returnedIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    completedIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, CompletedActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("COMPLETED").setIndicator("Completed")
                        .setContent(completedIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height=75;
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height=75;
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height=75;
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height=75;

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId){
            if("ASSIGNED".equals(tabId)){
                tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(tabId);
            }else if("ACCEPTED".equals(tabId)){
                tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(tabId);
            }
        }
    });  


    }

}
```

I had it like many activities for the tabs. While trying to make it as views getting some problem. Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabContent does not have assignedLin as its child. Include assignedLin in FrameLayout. Right now it is not.

Comment: There is a linear Layout with the id assignedLin.

Comment: What was the mistake? I am having a similar error to you, but I don't know why. Thanks!